# ¿Cómo ordenar fechas en un Array con Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, underscorejs

Tengo un Array de fechas, estas todas en MomentJs, quiero poder ordenar de menor a mayor, ademas utilizo [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) y creo que podría funcionar con `_.sortBy` pero no logro analizar el ordenamiento:

```
available: false
from: m
  _d: Wed Dec 23 2015 09:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)
  _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
  _i: "2015-12-23T08:00:00"
  _isAMomentObject: true
  _isUTC: false
  _locale: q
  _pf: Object
  __proto__: m
time: "09:00"
until: m
  _d: Wed Dec 23 2015 09:14:00 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)
  _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
  _i: "2015-12-23T08:00:00"
  _isAMomentObject: true
  _isUTC: false
  _locale: q
  _pf: Object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ordenarlas puedes usar el método `getTime`, esto asegura una [comparación correcta](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2015/12/comparacion-de-fechas-en-javascript/) entre los elementos del arreglo:

```
// Con Underscore.js
var sortDates = function(array){
    return _.sortBy(array, function(date){
        return date.getTime(); // Si es una fecha de Moment.js puedes usar .valueOf()
    });
};

var result = sortDates(arreglo);
```

Si estás usando solo JavaScript puedes usar el método `sort`

```
arreglo.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.getTime() - b.getTime();
});
```

Nota que en el caso de Underscore.js el arreglo original no se modifica, sino que se obtiene un nuevo arreglo, a diferencia de usar solo JavaScript.

Puedes ver un demo en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okn7edv4/)

Answer (score 1):

Esta forma tiene precision de hasta milisegundos.

```
var ordenadas = _.sortBy(fechas, function(m) { 
   return m.toDate().getTime();
});
```

Recuerda que `_.sortBy`, siempre ordena de forma ascendente. Si necesitas las fechas de forma descendente deberías utilizar. `reverse()`.

```
var descendente = ordenadas.reverse();
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcionando, debes abrir la consola (F12) para ver los resultados.

```js
var fechas = [moment("2014-10-01T00:10:12.233Z"),
              moment("2014-09-01T00:10:12.232Z"),
              moment("2015-08-01T00:10:12.234Z"),
              moment("2013-07-01T00:10:12.231Z")];

var ordenadas = _.sortBy(fechas, function(m) { 
   return m.toDate().getTime();
});

for(var i = 0; i < ordenadas.length; i++) {
  console.log(ordenadas[i].format());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hola puedes [formatearlas](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) y utilizar la función sort de javascript o la misma librería `momentjs` para 
manejar la condicion [is-before](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)
de ordenamiento sortBy de underscore

Answer (score 0):

Luego de analizar bien pude llegar a este resultado.

```
orderArray = _.sortBy(array, function (trip) {
       return moment(trip.from);
      });
```

de esta manera las fechas contenidas en `trip.from` son capaces de ser ordenadas.